# Suggestions to boot OnePlus 3T without any physical buttons?

Tags: boot, buttons, oneplus-3

As the title says, any suggestions for this would be welcome as I have lost the use of both power and volume buttons. Device is not rooted, running Oreo. I have access to both Windows and MAC computers.

Thanks in advance